# How does order_by behave in sql when order_by column is having duplicate values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I'm using a query to fill null values using 'first_value' function of sql
The entire query with example is as below:

```
WITH example (date,close) AS 
(VALUES 
    ('12:00:00',3),
    ('12:00:01',4),
    ('12:00:01',5),
    ('12:00:03',NULL),
    ('12:00:04',NULL), 
    ('12:00:05',3)
)
SELECT * INTO temporary table market_summary FROM example;

select 
    date, 
    cccc, 
    first_value(cccc) over (partition by grp_close) as corrected_close
from (
      select date, close as cccc,
             sum(case when close is not null then 1 end) over (order by date) as grp_close
      from   market_summary
) t
```

The result is :

```
    date      cccc   corrected_close
1   12:00:00    3       3
2   12:00:01    4       4
3   12:00:01    5       4
4   12:00:03    NULL    4
5   12:00:04    NULL    4
6   12:00:05    3       3
```

Here in this example, 'date' is used as order_by column in the query but it has a duplicate of '12:00:01'. The null values are being filled with '4' which is ideally not correct as i want null values to be filled with the previous non-null values which in this case is '5' not '4' so that result should have been as below:

```
    date       cccc   corrected_close
1   12:00:00    3       3
2   12:00:01    4       4
3   12:00:01    5       5
4   12:00:03    NULL    5
5   12:00:04    NULL    5
6   12:00:05    3       3
```

How do I modify the query to meet my requirement?

Comment: Are you using MySQL, Oracle or Postgresql?

Comment: *"How does order_by behave in sql when order_by column is having duplicate values?"* ANSI/ISO Standard SQL is defined to return non deterministic (random) results for non unique column values for duplicated values. To get 100% deterministic (fixed) always you also atleast add a column to the ORDER BY clause with a primary or unique key.

Comment: Meaning for the example data `1 | 12:00:00, 2 | 12:00:01, 3 | 12:00:01` and `ORDER BY date` you don't know which record will be first or last with the `12:00:01` value the resulting order for those record are non deterministic (random), to get non deterministic (random) results you would have to use `ORDER BY date, id` assuming the id is primary key.

Comment: You need to use `first_value(cccc) over (partition by grp_close order by date, cccc) as corrected_close` -- Added Order by clause

Comment: for @jarlh im using postgres

Answer (score 0):

You should change the window function so that you get the correct value:

```
last_value(cccc) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY grp_close ORDER BY date)
```

This is the way defined by the SQL standard, but a lot of databases don't implement the standard in this respect. Since you tagged a lot of databases, it is difficult to give a generic answer that works for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `lag( . . . ignore nulls)`.  But, Postgres doesn't support that.

Here is one work-around:

```
select e.*, coalesce(close, max(close) over (partition by grp))
from (select e.*, count(close) over (order by date) as grp
      from example e
     ) e;
```

You can even do this without a subquery:

```
select e.*,
       coalesce(close,
                (array_remove(array_agg(close) over (order by date), null))[array_upper(array_remove(array_agg(close) over (order by date), null), 1)]
               )

from example e;
```